# How to display comment status with radio buttons?

Tags: views, nodes

How can I display the comment status (open and close) with radio buttons in the comment submit page? I want it be selectable during comment submission by the user.

---

Actually, I have a content type which has an comment field with two radio buttons:

1. Satisfied
2. Unsatisfied

My goal is that, when users select the "Satisfied" button, the comment will be closed automatically; when the "Unsatisfied" button is selected, the users are able to send the next comment.

Comment: welcome to Drupal Answers, your question appears to lack clarity on what you are trying to achieve here, please elaborate on the workflow that you wish to accomplish and where you are stuck in trying to do so.

Comment: It looks to me like you want some sort of [voting](https://www.drupal.org/search/site/vote?f[0]=ss_meta_type%3Amodule) process, with a way to explain the choice made. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use [rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module for your comment, then use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to close the comment on specific node.